Closed-form expression for nested summation with exponentially decaying terms
I'm working on a problem that involves a nested summation with exponentially decaying terms. The expression is as follows:
\begin{align}
S(t) = \sum_{i=1}^t a_2^{t-i} \sum_{j=1}^i a_1^{i-j}
\end{align}
where $a_i\in\mathbb{C}~\forall i$, $0 < |a_2|, |a_1| < 1$. I'm interested in finding out if this summation has a closed-form expression for either the finite $t$ case or for $t\rightarrow\infty$.
More generally, does this have a solution for the case of $K$ nested sums, i.e.
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^t a_K^{t-i} \sum_{j=1}^i a_{K-1}^{i-j} \dots \sum_{l=1}^ka_1^{k-l}?
\end{align}
Any insights or references to similar problems would be greatly appreciated!

$u_j$'s have any special form?

@Sounak I think of $u_j$'s as being Gaussian distributed with mean 0 and variance 1.

Do $\sum_{j=1}^i u_j$ or $\sum_{j=1}^\infty u_j$ have closed forms? If not, there doesn't seem to be a hope that these complicated variants will.

@GregMartin thanks for the question, I removed the $u_j$ dependence as the assumption is that $u$ can either be factored out or it can be treated as a constant in the geometric series formula.

Now it's more promising—indeed every inner sum that remains is a geometric series, which will produce more geometric series for the next-most-inner sums, and so on.

If you squint, this looks like a certain matrix multiplication.  Also it seems that the sum converges to $\prod_{i=1}^K \frac{1}{1-a_i}$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$.
